# How can I create a initialized method in java canvas?

Tags: java, canvas

Im trying to make a game in java. My problem is that I dont have a initialized method or when I try to create one, my repaint() method substitute my initialized method. I need an initialized to generate my map. Because my map is a list of polygons and I want to set the background when clicked. So, if it is generating every time in a loop called by repaint() I cant do that.

My code:

Run Method:

```
 @Override
   public void run()
  {
     while (isRunning)
        {
            backPanel.repaint();
        }
 }
```

My backpanel class

```
 int jogadas = 1;
```

Paint method:

```
@Override
    public void paint(Graphics canvasOriginal)
      { 
        super.paint(canvasOriginal);
        canvas = (Graphics2D) canvasOriginal;
        canvas.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        mapa = new Mapa(canvas);
        mapa.DrawMapa(100, 50, 5);
       getJogada();

  }

   int getVez() {
   if(jogadas % 2 == 0) {
       return 1;
   }
   return 0;
 }   

void getJogada() {
     Hexagono hex = mapa.selecionarHex(x, y);
     if(!hex.getPrenchido()) {
        if(jogador1.getNumero() == getVez()) {
              hex.Preencher(jogador1.getColor());
        } else {
              hex.Preencher(jogador2.getColor());
        }
        jogadas++;
     }

}
```

Obs: the  mapa.selectHex selects the hex in a list. The hex.preencher() fill the hex polygon.

Result:

[image: It is changing every 1ms the filled background red to blue]

Comment: What do you mean by "initialized method"?  Methods don't have state and don't need to be "initialized".  Your question doesn't make much sense to me.

Comment: I need to load just one time my map. That why I need an init method.

Comment: Oh.  You mean an **initialization** method.  So which is this initialization method you are talking about?

Comment: I need to load map just one time. Because, if I load every 1000ms in my paint method, I cant have more than two filled polygons.